# How to setup Gruntfile / Yeoman to scaffold over a feature-centric directory structure

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, directory-structure, organization

When creating a new project using Yeoman's angularJS generator (yo angular), the app is initialiazed with the following directory structure:

> - app
>
>   - scripts
>
>     - controllers
>
>       - aFeatureController
>       - bFeatureController
>     - directives
>
>       - aFeatureDirective
>       - bFeatureDirective
>   - views
>
>     - aFeatureView
>     - bFeatureView

While this traditional MVC structure works well, I find it harder to navigate than a feature -centric structure, where all files related to the same section of the app are living under the same roof. In other words, I'd like to have the following structure instead:

> - app
>
>   - aFeature
>
>     - aFeatureController
>     - aFeatureDirective
>     - aFeatureView
>   - bFeature
>
>     - bFeatureController
>     - bFeatureDirective
>     - bFeatureView

Is it possible to configure gruntfile and Yeoman so that grunt keeps tasking and Yeoman scaffolding generators still function properly?

Comment: You can write your own task in GruntFile and Negate these from the usual tasks which is getting executed for the generated structure .

Comment: Can you also share the tasks that you are executing in grunt.

Comment: not trying to execute any custom task at this point, just the default set.

Comment: By default when you create a Yeoman app, it adds lot of tasks what are all the things that you want to run ?

Comment: I'd need to make sure that at least grunt can compile (concat, compass), minify (ngmin, uglify, htmlmin) and test (jshint, karma). Then i - maybe wrongly - assume that dist and livereload wouldn't be affected by folder structure changes

Answer (score 1):

The structure you pointed out is generated by the default angular yeoman generator.

For the feature based structure that you want, (which I personally like as well), can be generated by other yeoman generators like [generator-cg-angular](https://github.com/cgross/generator-cg-angular).

There are quite a few generators which do the same. You can find one that suits you best by searching for angular on yeoman. These generate this structure by default without having to change your grunt or writing a new generator.